# Interactive on-screen instructions

Tags: software-development, screen-recording

I'm looking for a program to help me train others how to do something.

Current practice involves me making a PowerPoint or video showing the instruction.

Another better method is me showing the process one-on-one but this is time consuming.

I'm envisioning a program that runs on top of the screen that guides someone through process.

For example if I need train sometime how to write an an email, the program will tell them to click the Chrome button,  then click Gmail, then click the compose button.

The program will have to sense where the mouse is on the screen and where the user is clicking.  How can this be done?

Comment: "`How can this be done?`" are you asking us to recommend some software (if so, please say so), or how to code it (if so, your question is badly off-topic here)